# PubNub access result in async method

Tags: c#, async-await, pubnub

I am writing an API that will grant access to a pubnub channel, but need to await granting access and return a result. Can someone advise how I can await for a response please?

> The return type of `.Async` is void

The method I call to grant access is a as follows;

```cs
pubnub.Grant()
            .Channels(new string[] {
            "channel"
            })
            .Read(true)
            .Write(true)
            .AuthKeys(new List<string>() { "xyz" }.ToArray())
            .TTL(0)
            .Async(new PNAccessManagerGrantResultExt((result, status) =>
            {
               //I need to await this and return the result in my method
            }));
```

> Since it does not return a task I cannot await it and my return statement would execute before this even completes.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have been sent the following solution from PubNub support that solves this issue, see below

```cs
var resultTask = new TaskCompletionSource<PNAccessManagerGrantResult>();

pubnub.Grant()
            .Channels(new string[] {
            "channel"
            })
            .Read(true)
            .Write(true)
            .AuthKeys(new List<string>() { "xyz" }.ToArray())
            .TTL(0)
            .Async(new PNAccessManagerGrantResultExt((result, status) =>
            {
               resultTask.TrySetResult(result);
            }));

var syncResult = resultTask.Task.Result;
```

Comment: `var syncResult = resultTask.Task.Result;` This line negates any benefit of using an `async` method. Read why here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx - particularly the section titled *Async all the way*

Comment: But you can't do anything until the grant has taken place so you can't possibly do it async. But My question would be: "Are you granting permissions to your server or to a client app?" Let me know because I have idifferent advice, respectively.

Comment: @CraigConover Exactly, I need to know the result. I'm granting to a client app with a short TTL.

Comment: You should be able to do the grant async and by the time the client app receives the auth-key, it should be properly propagated throughout all our PoPs but there is a chance that it will 403 on a request from the client due to it not fully propagating before that request is made.

The good news is that we have a new version of auth (Access Manager) that is not GA at this moment, that does not have this issue. (to be continued in next comment)

Comment: Workaround is to sleep 1s on the client side before making the request. That's not an desirable workaround though but better than a retry on a 403 from the client because the 403 will be cached for 5s. I will have engineering review in case there are better options. But auth v3 is the ultimate solution here.